# Why am I getting a segfault trying to add element to vector<vector<int>>(matrix implementation)?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, segmentation-fault

I have included a description of my C++ program a little further down, but I feel like the problem might be so basic the description is unnecessary. Essentially, I'm getting a segfault in my "parse_matrix" method. I've done some debugging and marked the line where the run ends, but I can't figure out what exactly is wrong. What I'm trying to do in the line is to use cin to grab a number from the input file and put it into a matrix (implemented as a vector< vector< int >>) at index [i][j]. I've tried different ways to set the value in the matrix (first

Here's the program description:

I am writing a program that basically will take an input file containing information on matrices and an operation to perform, and will output the resulting matrix. The first line in the input file will say either "add" or "multiply", the second line will say how many matrices there will be. Then, there will be two lines for each matrix, the first of which has two numbers separated by a space that determine the dimension (rows columns) of the following matrix, whose contents will be written in a single line and grouped into rows (so a 2x2 matrix would be A(1,1) A(1,2) A(2,1) A(2,2) (1,1 is the top left, 1,2 is the top right, 2,1 is the bottom left, 2,2 is the bottom right).

An example input file, which tells the program to add 3 matrices, all of dimensions 2x2:

```
add                                                                      
3
2 2
1 2 3 4
2 2
1 1 1 1
2 2 
1 0 1 0
```

Here's my code (I've marked where the problem seems to be occuring). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//define dot product
int dot(vector<int> a, vector<int> b){
    int c=0;
    int size = a.size();
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
        c += a[i]*b[i];
    }
    return c;
}

//define Matrix struct
struct Matrix {
    vector<vector<int>> mtrx;
    int m;
    int n;

    //overloading "+" for adding matrices
    Matrix operator+ (const Matrix& b){
        Matrix c;
        for (int i=0; i<b.m; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<b.n; j++){

                c.mtrx[i][j] = this->mtrx[i][j] + b.mtrx[i][j];
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    //overloading "*" for multiplying matrices
    Matrix operator* (const Matrix& b){
        Matrix c;
        for (int i=0; i<b.m; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<b.n; j++){
                vector<int> temp;
                for (int k=0; k<b.m; k++){
                    temp.push_back(b.mtrx[k][j]);
                }
                c.mtrx[i][j] = dot(this->mtrx[i],temp);
            }
        }
        c.n = b.n;
        return c;
    }

};

//will apply the designated operation to two matrices
Matrix operation(Matrix a, Matrix b, string op_type){
    Matrix c;
    if (op_type=="add"){
        if (a.m == b.m && a.n == b.n) {
            c = a+b;
        }
        else {
            cout<<"Dimensions do not match. Addition cannot be performed.";
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else if (op_type == "multiply"){
        if (a.n == b.m){
            c = a*b;
        }
        else {
            cout<<"Inner dimensions do not match. Multiplication cannot be performed.";
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else {
        cout<<"This program does not "<<op_type<<" matrices. It only adds or multiplies.";
        exit(1);
    }
    return c;
}

//reads line and sets matrix elements
void parse_matrix(Matrix *p){
    int m,n;
    cin>>m>>n;

    p->m = m;
    p->n = n;

    for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++){
             int x;
             cin>>x;
/************THIS IS WHERE THE SEGFAULT OCCURS***************/
             ((p->mtrx)[i]).push_back(x);
        }
    }
}

//prints matrix elements in a line (row, column) lexicographical ordering      using cout 
void print_matrix(Matrix matrix){
    int m = matrix.m;
    int n = matrix.n;

    for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++){
            cout<<matrix.mtrx[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;

    }
}

//main will read in type of operation, number of matrices, and individual matrices
//each matrix resides on a line, and will be parsed into rows and columns
//each matrix line will be preceded by a line of two ints that specifies the matrix dimensions
int main() {

    string op_type;
    cin>>op_type;
    int num;
    cin>>num;

    Matrix matrix;
    Matrix final;

    parse_matrix(&final);

    for (int k=1; k<num; k++) {
        parse_matrix(&matrix);
        operation(final, matrix, op_type);
    }

    print_matrix(final);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's `temp` in `parse_matrix`? As far as I can tell, it's an uninitialized variable, and the code can't possibly segfault because it doesn't even compile, let alone run.

Comment: There are many things wrong with this code.  You can start fixing them by properly initializing your Matrix variables.  The way you have it now the vectors are empty and you crash when you try to access them.

Answer (score 0):

This code has a problem:

```
Matrix c;
...
c.mtrx[i][j] =
```

This accesses out of bounds. `c.mtrx` was created as a 0x0 matrix but you try to access indices `i,j`.  The `[]` operator does not automatically expand the size of the vector.

The line you marked probably has the same issue:

```
((temp.mtrx)[i]).push_back(x);
```

Your code does not show what `temp` is but probably it's a global variable that does not have as many as `i` rows yet.

Instead you need to make sure that a vector entry at index `[i]` already exists before you try writing to its value.  You can use `push_back` as an alternative.

Comment: but in my for loop, i is initially 0. if I declare a vector<int> without explicitly setting its contents, it will still have an element at [0] right?

Comment: Ok I dont know why I thought that, just tested it out and apparently the vector is just completely empty. Is this the same for arrays? My confusion I think comes from the fact that I know the value of an array is essentially the pointer to its first entry, which then points to the next entry and so on. I know that vector elements are not stored contiguously. So how does a vector start?

Comment: You can use the `resize` function to resize a vector. Or you can specify the size in the constructor.  You'll need to do this for each individual row.   C-style arrays aren't resizable so I'm not sure what you were talking about.

Comment: Example for the `operator+` function: `Matrix c( b.m, vector<int>(b.n) );`  . Although in this case `Matrix c = b;` would be simpler and then use `+=` instead of `+` in the following code.   For the `operator*` function you have some redesigning to do - you try to write values and then change dimensions at the end, which isn't going to work.